# Desordenar palabras de un txt

Tags: java, archivo, arraylist

Tengo un programa hecho en JAVA que muestra en consola un archivo *txt* que contiene una lista de palabras ordenadas alfabéticamente:

```
try{
  FileReader fr = new FileReader("archivo.txt");
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
  String [] file = {"archivo.txt"};
  ArrayList<String> fileList =new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(file));    
  String cadena;
  while((cadena=br.readLine())!=null){
     System.out.println(""+cadena);
   }
  }catch(Exception e){ }
 }
}
```

Necesito que al guardarlas en un `ArrayList` las desordene, y las muestre así en consola. Probé con:

```
Collections.shuffle(arrayList);
```

Y nada ¿Qué me sugieren?

Comment: El método Collections.suffle desordena una lista de cadenas no la lista de Objetos buffer que tienes abierta. Por tanto deberías guardar las palabras del fichero en la lista y desordenarla con ese mismo método.

Comment: Por favor, pon un ejemplo completo (por ejemplo, estás haciendo `Collections.shuffle` de un `arrayList` que no aparece para nada en el código de arriba. Con lo que muestras, tenemos que "adivinar" como funciona tu código, y la bola de cristal la tengo en el taller. Revisa como incluir un [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En Efecto el método [`shuffle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List)) se emplea  para desordenar aleatoria mente  los elementos de una Lista, Entrando ya en su código, recomendar emplear [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), además  esta intentando cambiar el orden de forma incorrecta, ya que el array tendrá solo un `String` que será el nombre del archivo. *(teniendo en cuenta que en el ejemplo en lugar de arraylist como parámetro de shuffle se haya referido a fileList creado)*

Para tener en la lista los elementos , deberá añadir el elemento al `ArrayList` creado anteriormente dentro del `while`.

**Posible código final**

```
public static void main (String args []) throws IOException{
  String line = "";
  ArrayList<String> fileList = new ArrayList<>();
  try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("archivo.txt"))) {
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
        fileList.add(line); /* Agregamos la Línea leída a la lista */
      }
 }
  System.out.println("LISTA DESORDENADA ");
  Collections.shuffle(fileList); /* Modificar Orden*/
  /* Imprimir en una sola línea , puede optar por un ciclo */
  System.out.println(fileList.toString()); 
}
```

Comment: Iba a añadir que además usara try-with-resources pero ya lo has hecho tú :-)